# How to sum up two images on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

How can I sum up two bands of different images using Google Earth Engine.

I uploaded two images to the GEE, but I would like to know how to do the sum between them: image1 + image2 = image3.

I try, but fail

```
var image3 = ee.ImageCollection('image1', 'image2').merge(sum)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't merge them into a collection. Also have a look at the documentation, I know it can be overwhelming but it's more than helpful.

```
var image3 = image1.add(image2)
```

Comment: Hello @JonasV. I tested your code, but I discovered another problem. Image1 has pixels with a "nodata" value. This nodata was not included, why is it?

Comment: Because nodata + x = nodata. If you want to include it, you have to convert nodata to a value first

Comment: hello @JonasV, really convert the nodata to a value. I managed to solve my problem here. add () is very efficient.